# Windows cmd git cannot access .git/config after new user created

Tags: windows, git, cmd

I was using git from windows cmd. I created a new user with **administrator** role on my OS. When I login with this new user, although I access git command from cmd, I cannot do any action for existing repository. 
e.g. When I say `git status` in the repo folder the error is

```
warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
```

I checked the repo's .git folder and it's content. All the files/folder has permission for that new user.

Comment: Have you logged in as this new user (other than runas) so the profile could be setup?